# Checking multiple items in a list in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if elements of a  list contains a string, but it has to be in order.

Example:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 't', 'd', 'e']

z = 'bt'
```

I want to see if z is in x in that order.

I know I could do:

```
if all(item in x for items in z):
    # do something
```

But that doesn't check the order(the t in 'bt' doesn't have to come after b it could be anywhere on the list)

I know you can do a nested loop, or convert the list to a string and then work with it but that isn't really efficient...

Any help?

Comment: Why do you think converting the list to a string will be inefficient?

Comment: @Imperishable Didn't explain properly. I just want to know if there is a better way of doing it besides the two i listed

Comment: If you convert the list to a string (which has a convenient implementation: `''.join(x)`), this sounds like the substring problem, which has multiple known efficient algorithms. Python probably uses one of them to implement the `in` operator and `find` function for strings.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, you can implement [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), but beware: using actual python loops to do anything library functions could do is probably not efficient.

Comment: @ImperishableNight I think, this is not a substring problem. OP says **"But that doesn't check the order(the t in 'bt' doesn't have to come after b it could be anywhere on the list)"**. That means the solution must return `True` for `'bt'`, `'bd'` and `'at'`, not just only for `'bt'`. So, `'bd'` is not a substring. Please, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Alperen in which case you can cheat slightly like `if re.search('.*?'.join(z), ''.join(x))`...

Comment: @Alperen "Come after" can also mean "immediately after", and I assumed that because the opposite is "anywhere else" rather than simply "before". Also, I assumed that if the asker didn't realize that it's not a substring problem, then it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the list if the list contains the character. Use this method:

```
def control(x, z):
    for char in z:
        if char not in x:
            return False
        else:
            x = x[x.index(char) + 1:]
    return True
```

Let's try:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 't', 'd', 'e']
z1 = 'ba'
z2 = 'bt'
z3 = 'bd'

print(control(x, z1))
print(control(x, z2))
print(control(x, z3))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
```